# Displaying the check box dynamically

Tags: java, android

When i try to display the checkbox  dynamically, each overlaps with other.here is the code i tried

```
while(pCur.moveToNext()){
    String phoneNo=pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));    
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.r1);
        ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(MainActivity.this);
        CheckBox c1 = new CheckBox (MainActivity.this);
        c1.setText(name);
        c1.setBackgroundColor( -16776961);
        LayoutParams lp=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.bottomMargin=10;
        LayoutParams lp1=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                                 c1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        scroll.addView(c1);
        scroll.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        rl.addView(scroll);
}
```

how to display each checkbox in next line??

Comment: Used `Linear Layout` instead of `Relative Layout` and set `Orientation Vertical`

Comment: @SimplePlan if i change my layout to linear then it displays "unfortunately app has been stopped"

Comment: @DB why? put your all code and logcat

Comment: @SimplePlan...may be he just changed his layout not his code.

Comment: @SimplePlan Yes its opening now, but i cant scroll vertically now.

Comment: @HamidShatu yes you are right i didn't change the reference object in oncreate method. thanks